# libgdx: IOS on screen keyboard not firing events consistently

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, on-screen-keyboard

I am having trouble with InputProcessor only on my IOS build.  This code works for Desktop and Android builds but not iOS.

Basically, I need to catch an event anytime the user types on the onscreen keyboard.  But in iOS I only see my println for keyTyped intermittantly and only when i type on the on screen keyboard fast. All the other touches just show a new line in the console, I am not sure where this new line output is originating from.

The issue seems to stem from however iOS sends events back to my application and how LibGDX InputProcessor receives them.  I have tried creating my own object that extends TextField and implements InputProcessor then set the instance of that object as the inputProcessor but i get the same result.  If i touch anywhere on the screen that is not the iOS onscreen keyboard i get events firing consistently.

This is what the iOS console output looks like this when i type very fast, if i type slow the println never shows up:

```
game name field key typed!


game name field key typed!






game name field key typed!
```

Doing the same thing on an android device (nexus 7) yields the following (which is what I would expect):

```
I/System.out: game name field key down!
I/System.out: game name field key up!
I/System.out: game name field key typed!
I/System.out: game name field key down!
I/System.out: game name field key up!
I/System.out: game name field key typed!
I/System.out: game name field key down!
I/System.out: game name field key up!
I/System.out: game name field key typed!
```

here is my code:

```
public class AccountScreen implements Screen {


final PieTherapy game;
private Stage stage;

private TextField gameNameField;

public AccountScreen(final PieTherapy game) {
    this.game = game;
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    Viewport vp = new StretchViewport(PieTherapy.WORLD_WIDTH, PieTherapy.WORLD_HEIGHT, game.cam);
    stage = new Stage(vp);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    TextField.TextFieldStyle tfs = new TextField.TextFieldStyle();
    tfs.font = game.fontTitle;
    tfs.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    tfs.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(game.assets.get("menus/textline.png", Texture.class)));
    tfs.focusedBackground = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(game.assets.get("menus/textline-selected.png", Texture.class)));
    tfs.cursor = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(game.assets.get("menus/cursor.png", Texture.class)));

    gameNameField = new TextField("", tfs);
    gameNameField.setWidth(PieTherapy.WORLD_WIDTH * .80f);
    gameNameField.setFocusTraversal(true);
    gameNameField.setPosition(PieTherapy.WORLD_WIDTH *.05f, game.WORLD_HEIGHT * .68f);
    // see if the player information has already been entered (edit mode)
    gameNameField.setText(game.primaryPlayer.gameName);
    gameNameField.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("game name field touch up!");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("game name field touch down!");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
            System.out.println("game name field key down!");
            return super.keyDown(event, keycode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
            System.out.println("game name field key up!");
            return super.keyUp(event, keycode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(InputEvent event, char character) {
            System.out.println("game name field key typed!");
            return super.keyTyped(event, character);
        }
    });

    gameNameField.getOnscreenKeyboard().show(true);
    gameNameField.setCursorPosition(gameNameField.getText().length());

    stage.addActor(gameNameField);

    stage.setKeyboardFocus(gameNameField);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Your name in the game! You can stick with the\nautomatically generated" +
                    "one or change to your own.\n Red: name is not available, " +
                    "green: available.",
            PieTherapy.WORLD_WIDTH *.36f,
            PieTherapy.WORLD_HEIGHT *.93f);

    game.batch.end();

    update(delta);
}

private void update(float delta) {

    stage.act(delta);

    stage.draw();

    game.batch.begin();

    game.batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

LibGDX version: 1.9.6
RoboVM (MobiDevelop) version : 2.3.1

I guess i can always roll my own on-screen keyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to follow up incase anyone finds themselves here in the future.  I ended up creating my own on screen keyboard, I could not get the events to work consistently in iOS.

If anyone has anything they want to add in the future i will check in to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm seeing issues with the iOS simulator keyboard, but it's working fine in a physical device, at least an iPhone 7 I own myself. I still have to go through some debugging, though. Came here looking for something that could explain my issues with the simulator.

Comment: JFTR, what I found out with the simulator is that, for any key I type I get two keyType events instead of only one, and the second always come with the character \u0008, that's incidentally the back space/delete key, so what's happening is that every char I enter, it's automatically deleted. Still trying to figure out why...